# Python append method not working correctly

Tags: python, arrays, list, methods, dictionary

```
def sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 1:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if semester1 == 2:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def main():

    selectionSEM1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    selectionSEM2 = []

    semester1 = {

    1: ["e", "f", "g", "h"], 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ,

    }

    SEM1period1 = sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1)
    SEM1period2 = sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1)

    print SEM1period1
    print SEM1period2

main()
```

When I run this code it prints out SEM1period1 fine, as ["e", "f", "g", "h"], but the second method sem1Sort2, seems not to save anything into SEM1period2 - as the print statement prints out []

UPDATE:

```
def sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 1:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 2:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def sem1Sort3(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 3:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

def main():

    selectionSEM1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]
    selectionSEM2 = []


    semester1 = {
    1: ["e", "f", "g", "h"], 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ,
    3: ["i", "j", "k", "l"]
    }

    SEM1period1 = sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1)
    SEM1period2 = sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1)
    SEM1period3 = sem1Sort3(semester1, selectionSEM1)

    print SEM1period1
    print SEM1period2
    print SEM1period3

main()
```

Why does print SEM1period3 return none?

Comment: After fixing the error pointed out by fledgling, both the functions `sem1Sort1` and `sem1Sort2` would be exactly the same, so why two different functions? Moreover, `list` is a _type_ in python, so creating a variable with name `list` is not so wise.

Comment: Guys, you don't need to vote me down... I'm just a novice looking for some answers. Sorry.

Comment: Please don't add more questions after it has been answered.

Comment: u don't have any  return value so use "return list" in sem1Sort3 method ...hereafter first trace your self after that you can ask question.

Comment: New question should be posted as, well, new questions. Feel free to reference to this one when posting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are comparing `semester1` with integer but `semester1` is `dict` object in `sem1Sort2` function,

```
    for period in semester1:
        if semester1 == 2:
```

Actually you have to compare integer with key of `dict` like this ,

```
    for period in semester1:
        if period == 2:
```

And your rest of will be like this ,

```
    def sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 1:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1):

    list = []

    for period in semester1:
        if period == 2:
            for index in semester1[period]:
                if index in selectionSEM1:
                    list.append(index)

    return list

def main():

    selectionSEM1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    selectionSEM2 = []

    semester1 = {

    1: ["e", "f", "g", "h"], 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ,

    }

    SEM1period1 = sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1)
    SEM1period2 = sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1)

    print SEM1period1
    print SEM1period2

main()
```

Output:

```
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Now neither are returning anything...?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit of a novice and you have to give me a bit more direction, sorry.

Comment: Actually, `for period in semester1:` and `for period in semester1.keys():` does the same thing.

Comment: @LucasGrillos you are missing `return ` statement in function `sem1Sort3`.

Comment: @LucasGrillos you have to write `return list` at the end of function `sem1Sort3`.

Comment: @LucasGrillos If you are satisfied with my help , can you please accept my answer ?

Comment: I think pressing the green check mark does it right?

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

You don't need to loop over all dict entries and pick out the matching one - this makes the whoole usage of a dict pointless.

Instead, you can tell the dict to give you the value associated with the given key. You can do so in the `main()` function, reducing the function to

```
def semSort(semester, selection):
    list = []
    for index in semester:
        if index in selection:
            list.append(index)
    return list
```

which you can call in the `main()` function such as

```
def main():
    selectionSEM1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    selectionSEM2 = []
    semester1 = {
        1: ["e", "f", "g", "h"], 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ,
    }

    SEM1period1 = semSort(semester1[1], selectionSEM1)
    SEM1period2 = semSort(semester1[2], selectionSEM1)

    print SEM1period1
    print SEM1period2

main()
```

and you'll achieve what you want.

You can even refine it:

```
def semSort(semester, selection):

    result = []
    sel_set = set(selection)    
    for index in semester:
        if index in sel_set:
            result.append(index)

    return result
```

The set makes the lookup faster.

```
def semSort(semester, selection):
    sel_set = set(selection)
    return [index for index in semester if index in sel_set]
```

is even more compact.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1):
 list = []
 for period in semester1:
   if period == 1:
     for index in semester1[period]:
       if index in selectionSEM1:
          list.append(index)

 return list

def sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1):
 list = []
 for period in semester1:
  if period == 2:
   for index in semester1[period]:
    if index in selectionSEM1:
       list.append(index)
 return list

def main():
 selectionSEM1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
 selectionSEM2 = []
 semester1 = {
 1: ["e", "f", "g", "h"], 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ,
 }
 SEM1period1 = sem1Sort1(semester1, selectionSEM1)
 SEM1period2 = sem1Sort2(semester1, selectionSEM1)
 print SEM1period1
 print SEM1period2
main()
```

Comment: you wrote like (if semester == 2:)this takes total dictionary value so we want mention the particular key value

Comment: In order to make this a good answer, you could point out the differences and elaborate a bit on them.